# Android Macro Recorder

Tags: android, automation

I have been searching around looking for a good macro recorder that will not only record presses or touches but as well as button pressing. I have found no app like what I have been looking for. Can anyone help me. What I basically want to record is; Lock; Unlock; Swipe. Very basic function that every macro I have found doesn't support. Note: I am rooted.

Comment: Ok, seriously! I was told by a higher authority to post here and no one is answering. Its been months!